# Python: import multiple modules AS

Tags: python, import, module

Before I ask, I should note I recognize this is bad practice, but:

**how can you bind multiple modules to the same local name on import?**

For example:

```
import a and b and c as d
```

A little background for those of you just chomping at the bit to tell me never do this: The (large, renowned) company I work for has miraculously managed to create an entire library of python modules without clashing names for their core piece of software, and they import them all into the global namespace. So for instance, at the beginning of most scripts they do:

```
from cmds_core import *
from cmds_basic import *
from cmds_blah import *
```

for like a couple dozen modules.

I just want to import these into a single cmds_all in my scripts instead of leaving them in the open or having to figure out which module each function came from.

Comment: That isn't possible in the way you suggest.  You would have to create another module that imports everything from those modules, and then import that new module.

Comment: You could write another module that simply imports all of those functions into its namespace in `__init__.py`. Then just import your new module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At face value it's impossible. A single name can only have one binding at any one time. However, if you put your

```
from cmds_core import *
from cmds_basic import *
from cmds_blah import *
```

into `d.py`, then `import d` will do what you might be asking for.